# Is there something like mulitiSet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, set, red-black-tree, multiset

I know that JavaScript now has [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), but I wonder if there is something to realize the function of *multiSet*, or if there is some framework that has the functions of multiset which I really need a lot.

Or I have to code it by myself to do the research of *Red-Black Tree*?

Comment: @jfriend00 Exactly this search brought me here, following your instructions would create an infinite loop :-)

Comment: You don't need a redblack tree, what you could probably use is a sorted list, binary search, and a operator for merging sorted lists.

Answer (score 3):

There are no built-in multiset structure, but [there are some libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=multiset&page=1&ranking=popularity) that have such:

- [mnemonist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mnemonist) → [`MultiSet`](https://yomguithereal.github.io/mnemonist/multi-set)
- [TSTL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tstl) → [`TreeMultiSet`](http://samchon.github.io/tstl/api/classes/std.treemultiset.html)

Feel free to add your favorite library in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own multiset using the Builtin map type and numerical values:

```js
class Multiset {
    _backing = new Map();
    add(value) {
        if (this._backing.has(value)) {
            this._backing.set(value, 1 + this._backing.get(value));
        } else {
            this._backing.set(value, 1);
        }
    }

    delete(value) {
        if (this._backing.get(value) > 0) {
            this._backing.set(value, this._backing.get(value) - 1);
        } else {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    get(value) {
        if (this._backing.get(value) > 0) {
            return this._backing.get(value);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it came in at the top of my search. I've ended up using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy) (similar to [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#countBy)):
For example,

```
_.countBy([1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1])
```

gives the result

```
{ '1': 3, '2': 1, '4': 2 }
```