# How to count how many different objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating an array of objects. The array can have multiple same objects, so the final result would be something like:

```
MyArray = [obj1, obj1, obj2]
```

I want to count how many obj1 are in the array without declaring new variables since I want to use this method to store and count hundreds of different objects.

This is for an Angular web app to manage orders.

I was thinking of storing these objects as:

```
MyArray = [{obj1: 2}, {obj2: 1}]
```

but I can't figure out how to do it, nor how to increase the value when another obj is added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the condition of equality? Two "same" object = Same reference OR Same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), where you could take the objects as keys and count the occurences.

```js
var o1 = { a: 1 },
    o2 = { a: 1 },
    o3 = { a: 1 },
    array = [o1, o2, o1, o3, o1, o2],
    count = array.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o, (m.get(o) || 0) + 1), new Map);
    
console.log(Array.from(count));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to achieve this is to use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) followed by a filter.

Working example :

```js
const data = [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]

const result = [...new Set(data)].map(value => ({
    value,
    amount: data.filter(field => field === value).length
}))

console.log(result)
```

And using the formatting you want for your output :

```js
const data = [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9]

const result = [...new Set(data)].map(value => ({
    [value]: data.filter(field => field === value).length
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array=['a1','a1','b1','c1','c1']
var resultCount={}
array.forEach(ele=>{ resultCount[ele] = (resultCount[ele]||0) + 1;});
console.log(resultCount)
```

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion would be to try and use a library for JavaScript that includes `MultiSet` functionality (like in Java, for instance). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132242/is-there-something-like-mulitiset-in-javascript) could lead you to something that might work.

If you don't want to pull in another dependency, then you could define your own class that stores a `Map` property which uses the objects you want to store as keys and holds the count of the number of said objects as values ([more on JavaScript `Maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)).

You could do this by providing a method, say, `myMultiSet.add(obj)`, which will add the new element to the set if the `obj` is not already in the `Map` and set it's count value to `1`. If the `obj` is already in the `Map`, then simply increment the value by `1`.

#### Update

Here is a sample implementation:

```js
class MultiSet {
  constructor() {
    this.items = new Map();
  }
  
  add(obj) {
    if (this.items.has(obj)) {
      console.log(`${obj} is already in items. Incrementing.`);
      this.items.set(obj, this.items.get(obj) + 1);
    } else {
      console.log(`${obj} is new to items. Adding.`);
      this.items.set(obj, 1);
    }
  }
  
  getCount(obj) {
    return this.items.get(obj);
  }
};

let obj1 = { blah: 1, blah2: 2 };

let myMultiSet = new MultiSet();

myMultiSet.add(obj1);
myMultiSet.add(1);
myMultiSet.add('tree');
myMultiSet.add(1);
myMultiSet.add(obj1);

console.log(`Number of obj1 in set: ${myMultiSet.getCount(obj1)}`);
console.log(`Number of 'tree' in set: ${myMultiSet.getCount('tree')}`);
console.log(`Number of 1 in set: ${myMultiSet.getCount(1)}`);
```